# ASP.NET MVC 2 Updating problem

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to update my model through a class and not a form in ASP.Net MVC 2.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(string wo_number)
{
    WorkOrder wo = GetWorkOrder(wo_number);
    UpdateModel(wo);
    camprintRepository.Save();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { wo_number = wo_number });
}
```

I'm pulling the information from an outside source and I want it to update the entities in my applications database.

```
public WorkOrder GetWorkOrder (string wo_number)
 {
     UniFile uFile = uSession.CreateUniFile("WO");
     uFile.RecordID = wo_number;

     WO wo = new WO();

     wo.wo_id = wo_number;
     wo.sales_product_code = uFile.ReadNamedField("Sales_Code").ToString();
     wo.description = uFile.ReadNamedField("P_Desc").ToString();
     wo.part_number = uFile.ReadNamedField("Desc").ToString();
     wo.work_order_quantity = uFile.ReadNamedField("Qty_To_Mfg").ToString();
     wo.sales_order_quantity = uFile.ReadNamedField("Sod_Qty").ToString();

     GetWorkOrderOper(wo);


 }
```

I am using LINQ to SQL and as you can see there are some child objects that branch off from each workorder.

```
public void GetWorkOrderOper(WorkOrder wo)
{
    UniFile uFile = uSession.CreateUniFile("WPO");

    string key = wo.wo_id + "*" + wo.first_routing_sequence;

   while(key != wo.wo_id + "*")
   {
       uFile.RecordID = key;
       WPO wpo = new WPO();
       wpo.wpo_id = key;
       wpo.next_sequence_number = uFile.ReadNamedField("Next_Seq").ToString();
       wpo.run_hours = uFile.ReadNamedField("Plan_Run_Lbr_Time").ToString();
       key = wo.wo_id + "*" + wpo.next_sequence_number;
       wo.WPOs.Add(wpo);

   }
}
```

This is not updating the models and I'm not sure why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no SubmitChanges? Or is that in your UpdateModel?

Another cause might be no primary key in your underlying table

Comment: Missed that part on the question but yes I have that.

Comment: Primary key specified in the table as wo_id

Comment: Where do you do the InsertOnSubmit of the WO? Because you add wpo to your wo, but the original WO is not sent to the datacontext

Comment: I have AddWO function thats not stated that will InsertOnSubmit the WO if it doesn't exist.

Comment: The UpdateModel function?  Thats the built in function with MVC from the System.Web.MVC.Controller.cs class

Comment: The UpdateModel works in other cases when its user input from a form but not this way.

Comment: ok, not that familiar with MVC but more with Linq-2-sql just looking for the place where you do the actual DB work because I see no real problems in the code you posted... If you put a breakpoint just before your updateModel is the WO entity ok?

Comment: Yup, all the values I need are here looks good.  I'm thinking it's expecting values to come from the form so it does nothing.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint at the beginning of your AddWO function and see if you actually end up there?

Comment: Yea, I try to get the WO from the database and if returns a null I do the AddWO which works fine, but if its not null I execute the UpdateModel.  And it has no problem getting to the UpdateModel it just does nothing.

Comment: I'm thinking just deleting that WO then just adding the up to date one instead of doing the UpdateModel.

Comment: In my view you cannot delete it because you create a new one... WO wo = new WO(); Perhaps that is the issue? Anyway, it is more MVC that Linq2sql so i am afraid i cannot help you more

Comment: No problem thats for the assistance